# how through xslt variable value select node

Tags: templates, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, exslt

```
I am new to the xslt.

 - **Here is my input xml.**

<root>
        <MilleniumCreditCard>
            <Limit>20</Limit>
            <overdraft>yes</overdraft>
        </MilleniumCreditCard>
        <VisaCreditCard>
            <Limit>30</Limit>
            <overdraft>yes</overdraft>
        </VisaCreditCard>
        <OtherTypeCreditCard>
            <Limit>40</Limit>
            <overdraft>yes</overdraft>
        </OtherTypeCreditCard>
    </root>

As we can see we have 3 types of credit card.

But at a time only one type of card can come in the input xml. 
So the actual input xml would for example.

<root>
    <MilleniumCreditCard>
        <Limit>20</Limit>
        <overdraft>yes</overdraft>
    </MilleniumCreditCard>
</root>
```

I need to fetch the Limit and overdraft value for the same. but as I don't know which card will be coming , I have do a logic in my common template as shown below.

**Hence I have tried to write a common template**

**1st I am calling the template like below**

```
<output>
    <Limit>
    <xsl:call-template name="commontemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="inputname" select ="'Limit'"
    </xsl:call-template>
    </Limit>
  <overdraft>
    <xsl:call-template name="commontemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="inputname" select ="'overdraft'"
    </xsl:call-template>
    </overdraft>
    </output>
```

**Now my common template as below**

```
 <xsl:template name="commontemplate">
        <xsl:param name="inputname" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="root/MilleniumCreditCard != '' " />
            <xsl:value-of select="root/MilleniumCreditCard/$inputname" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="root/VisaCreditCard != '' " />
        <xsl:value-of select="root/VisaCreditCard/$inputname" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="root/OtherTypeCreditCard != '' " />
    <xsl:value-of select="root/OtherTypeCreditCard/$inputname" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="''">
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

but I am , getting blank value for Limit tag in output.
**but I want to get the value like below .**

```
<output>
<Limit>20</Limit>
<overdraft>yes</overdraft>
</output>
```

Can anybody help me with how to achieve this?
I will greatly appreciate for this help

Answer (score 0):

This is rather confusing. If the input will always have details of a single card only, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*/*"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: my input xml also have other tags apart from those 3 card type so just doing */* won't help

Comment: Please edit your question and show a representative example.

Answer (score 0):

Two XSLT/XPath features you need to learn about:

(a) the wildcard `*` selects any element regardless of its name, for example `/root/*` in your example.

(b) the union expression `(A|B|C)` selects an element whose name is `A` `B`, or `C`. In XSLT 2.0+ you can use this on the right-hand-side of `/`, for example `root/(A|B|C)`; in XSLT 1.0 you would have to write this as `(root/A | root/B | root/C)`.

Comment: Can you please share a sample code? Plz

Comment: No, I deliberately didn't do that. I think you're trying to learn the language by copying snippets, and that's a very bad way of learning. You need to understand the code that you're using, which means you need to do some reading.

Comment: Thanks for your input , when I am passing the tag name dynammically it is not. taking , e.g when I am giving 
<xsl:value-of select="//root/MilleniumCreditCard/Limit /> ,  I
 am getting proper value of Limit Tag but when I am storing Limit Tag into Variable <xsl:variable name="LimitTag" select ="'Limit'" />
Then passing the variable to fetch the value like below , it is not fetching <xsl:value-of select="//root/<xsl:value-of select="//root/MilleniumCreditCard/$LimitTag" /> . Not getting any output anything I am missing ?

Comment: Please don't raise supplementary questions in the form of a comment on an answer to a previous question. Start a new thread. But before you do that, search for "dynamic path expressions". Or preferably, do some reading. You won't get anywhere trying to make this work by trial and error.

Comment: ok, Thanks I will do a google search on this "dynamic path expressions". Thanks for your help